# How to write a proxy web server in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, proxy, pyqt

I had used the PyQt5 library to create a fully functional web browser minus the tabbed browsing. Now I want to have all the requests the browser sends to be routed through a proxy webserver I had created.
for that purpose I used QNetworkProxy to connect to the proxy server.

```
proxy = QNetworkProxy()
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy.HttpProxy)
proxy.setHostName("127.0.0.1")
proxy.setPort(60)
QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy)
```

Now when I run the proxy and then the browser I get an in-browser error page saying that the webpage (http://www.google.com) is not working (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE). It would appear that everything in the proxy is running somehow and that it closes the moment it accepts a connection and receives the data (finishes with process code 0).
I can't seem to pinpoint the issue so any help would be much appreciated!

Proxy code (written in Python 3.8):

```
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 60))

server_socket.listen(1)

while True:
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    request = client_socket.recv(1024)
    request = request.decode('utf-8')

    break
print("Client connected, requested connection to: " + request)
first_line = request.split('\n')[0]
# get url
url = first_line.split(' ')[1]
http_pos = url.find("://")  # find pos of ://
if (http_pos == -1):
    temp = url
else:
    temp = url[(http_pos + 3):]  # get the rest of url

port_pos = temp.find(":")  # find the port pos (if any)

# find end of web server
webserver_pos = temp.find("/")
if webserver_pos == -1:
    webserver_pos = len(temp)

webserver = ""
port = -1
if (port_pos == -1 or webserver_pos < port_pos):

    # default port
    port = 80
    webserver = temp[:webserver_pos]

else:  # specific port
    port = int((temp[(port_pos + 1):])[:webserver_pos - port_pos - 1])
    webserver = temp[:port_pos]

print("Request processed, routing it now...")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(30)
s.connect((webserver, port))
s.sendall(request.encode('utf-8'))

while True:
    # receive data from web server
    data = s.recv(4096)

    if (len(data) > 0):
        client_socket.send(data)  # send to browser/client
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Do you need to create the proxy from scratch?

Comment: If you are asking if I can just go and use a premade proxy from whatever place the answer is no. My goal with the proxy is eventually route the requests through Tor and that way I am going through Tor circuits without using Tor Browser. By this time I had implemented the code to connect to Tor and it would appear the proxy is indeed successful in connecting to both Tor and the internet, my issue now would be to take the type Response I am getting through Tor and send it back to the browser via the socket while keeping it readable by the browser code.

Comment: I was thinking about proxy.py https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py but I don't know if it would work for your Tor requirement, I have tested it and it works fine with Qt